# Catching Errors thrown by callback functions

Tags: javascript, callback, async-await

I have combined an asynchronous function with a callback because I need the asynchronous function to await another asynchronous function. The callback throws an error which I need to catch. How can I catch an error thrown in a callback called by the asynchronous function? The try-catch block in the code below does not work as long as someFunction is asynchronous

```
let someAsyncFunction = async () => {
    return true
}

let someFunction =  async (callback)=> {
    await someAsyncFunction()
    callback()
}

try {
    someFunction(()=> {
        throw ("Some error")
        console.log("Callback has been called")
    });

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

Here is the actual code. This first function works well by throwing the error. I am trying to get the second function to do the same.

```
async facebook(req, res, next) {
    throw ({status:405, message:"Method not allowed"})
}


async login(req, res, next) {
        let __promisifiedPassportAuthentication = function () {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
                    if(err)reject(err)
                    if(user === false || user === null)reject({message:"No such user"})
                })(req, res, next) 
            })
        }

        __promisifiedPassportAuthentication().catch((err)=>{
            //How do I get this error to be thrown by the (parent) function login?
            // Promise.reject(err)
            throw(err)

        })
    }
```

And the passport strategy

```
passport.use( new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, async (email, password, done) => {
  let [err, dontcare, care] = [];
  let person = {Email: email}

  ;[err, care] = await to (Familyfe.Person.which(person))
  //force err to have some value 
  err = true
  if(err)return done(err);

}));
```

Comment: "*a callback because I need the asynchronous function to await another asynchronous function*" - what? In the example you gave, there's no reason to use a callback at all, though the example looks really contrived. Maybe post your real-world use case?

Comment: @Bergi I have added all the code. I used the callback because passport.authenticate needs it.

Comment: Which of the many functions in that code does the `someFunction` with its `callback` parameter stand for? I can't make out the similarity.

Comment: You should just do `await __promisifiedPassportAuthentication();` or even `return __promisifiedPassportAuthentication();` - that way you get the promise returned from  `login()` to be rejected.

Comment: @Bergi `someFunction` with the `callback` is the passport strategy. I have tried what you have in your previous comment both `await __promisifiedPassportAuthentication()` and return `__promisifiedPassportAuthentication()` and they both work. And I notice this is similar to the answers that were already given below for the initial example code that I gave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The try-catch block in the code below does not work as long as `someFunction` is asynchronous

Of course it doesn't - `someFunction` is asynchronous and returns a promise. `try`/`catch` cannot catch asynchronous errors (promise rejections) unless you `await` that promise. If you don't call `someFunction` from an `async` function context, you will need to use the normal promise `catch` method:

```
try {
    await someFunction(()=> {
//  ^^^^^
        console.log("Callback has been called")
        throw new Error("Some error");
    });

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
}
```

or

```
someFunction(() => {
    console.log("Callback has been called")
    throw new Error("Some error");
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.message)
});
```

---

Of course there's no reason for that `someFunction` to take a callback. You should rather call the `someAsyncFunction` directly and use the promise that it returns for installing your callback

```
someAsyncFunction().then(() => {
    console.log("Callback has been called")
    throw new Error("Some error");
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.message)
});
```

or just not using a callback at all with `async`/`await`:

```
try {
    await someAsyncFunction()
    console.log("'Callback' code has been called")
    throw new Error("Some error");
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that code will work if you `await` the callback, like so:

```
let someFunction =  async (callback)=> {
    await someAsyncFunction()
    await callback()
}
```

But I think you can simplify this code. Do you really need `someFunction`? In that code, it doesn't seem to really simplify anything. (However, it would make sense to have a separate function like that if you're doing additional work in that function).

```
let someAsyncFunction = async () => {
    return true
}

// If top level `await` is allowed
try {
  await someAsyncFunction()
  console.log('someAsyncFunction has finished')
  throw "Some error"
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}

// If you can't use `await` here, you can just use the built-in Promise
someAsyncFunction()
  .then(() => {
    throw ("Some error")
    console.log("Callback has been called")
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```