# Unhandled exception while covered in try catch

Tags: javascript, exception, try-catch

The function `createPool` takes a callback, that will present an error if something went wrong with the connection. I want to throw an exception in case that happens `Connection pool failed with error`, but for some reason it keeps being unhandled and the try catch doesn't catch it. What can I change ?

```
try {
    // Create a connection pool which will later be accessed via the
    // pool cache as the 'default' pool.
    await oracledb.createPool({
        user: dbConfig.user,
        password: dbConfig.password,
        connectString: `${dbConfig.host}:${dbConfig.port}/${dbConfig.serviceId}` 
    }, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw `Connection pool failed with ${err.message}`;
            } else {
                console.log('Connection pool started');
            }
        }
    )
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    // propagate
    throw err;
}
```

The exceptions is thrown inside the callback as expected:

(node:32) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Connection pool failed with ORA-24415: Missing or null username.

But I can't catch her in my outer try catch

Comment: Can you add the *exact* error message you're getting?

Comment: You have `throw err;`  in the catch statement, I believe the error you are seeing is from there, You must handle it on the calling function.

Comment: These might help you a bit more : [Catching Errors thrown by callback functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49056125/3579960)

Comment: @CodingOtaku Nope, it never reaches the catch

Comment: If `oracledb.createPool` uses a success/error callback, chances are it isn't returning a Promise? Because if that's the case, you need to promisify it. `await new Promise((resolve, reject) => oracledb.createPool({...}, function (err) { if (err) reject(err); else resolve(); }));`

Comment: createPool returns `void`

Comment: Exactly, so you need to promisify it: https://jsfiddle.net/4vznu2dq/

Comment: Thanks that was it :) post as an answer